# LoadMoreItemsAsync is not called

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to implement lazy loading of items inside a ListView.
but `LoadMoreItemsAsync` is never called.

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MasterListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.News}">
        <!--
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        -->
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        News = new PaginateCollection<NormalNews>(LoadNews);
    }

    public PaginateCollection<NormalNews> News { get; set; }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<NormalNews>> LoadNews(uint size)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

PaginateCollection:

```
public class PaginateCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    Func<uint, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> load;
    public PaginateCollection(Func<uint, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> load)
    {
        this.load = load;
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(async c =>
        {
            var data = await load(count);
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
            return new LoadMoreItemsResult
            {
                Count = (uint)data.Count()
            };
        });
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't you also need to be setting the HasMoreItems to True? Don't see that in your code... cfr the Example given by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading

Comment: I'm setting the HasMoreItems in the Method `LoadNews()`,but it's not called,either

Comment: Same problem, in the constructor of the PaginateCollection set the HasMoreItems property to true. This will insure the first load trigger. Or with the new c# conventions public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; } = true;

Comment: By your comment, everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the PaginateCollection set the HasMoreItems property to true.**This will insure the first load trigger**. So the Method `LoadNews()` will be called and your logic will run.

```
public PaginateCollection(Func<uint, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> load)
{
    this.load = load;
    HasMoreItems = true;
}
```